# Cannot store instance of FirebaseUser

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
 FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getReference();

final FirebaseUser annonymsUser;

mAuth.signInAnnonmously();

annonymsUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser(); 

String AnnonymsUserID=annonymsUser.getUid(); // id:OxfVLTclVqNCPq6uTIUUdzxQoar1 

mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)...{}

String userId=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); //id:LKJDS7jhiudsoiudsdFYT453
```

annonmysUser.linkWithCredential(){}

String AnnonymsUserID=annonymsUser.getUid();  // id: LKJDS7jhiudsoiudsdFYT453

thus id for annonymsUser geting change after this line 
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password){} though annonymsUser is final

before : OxfVLTclVqNCPq6uTIUUdzxQoar1

after  : LKJDS7jhiudsoiudsdFYT453

So why cant i store instance at annonymsUser?,and why it is changing though it declared final?

is there any alternate way to store the annonymsUser instance????

Comment: is your annonymsUser and current user are different? as what I see is when a user starts with an app as annonymsUser it becomes your current user!! clear me here plz!

Comment: @AkshayNandwana i edited my question.do help plz

Answer (score 0):

we cannot store firebaseUser in Firebase variable,we will always get the current user.